# USB Enable and Disable

Tags: usb

I have created an application which enables and disables the USB port through registry, but i am facing one issue if i plugged in the pen drive into my system and changed the registry value to 4 i.e disable the USB port, the value gets changed but for the inserted pen-drive i am able to do the operations. Now after changing the value to 4 (disabling), i re insert the pen-drive then its not detected.

My problem after changing the value to 4 (disable mode) when the pen drive is plugged in to the system I am able to use its functionality. Disable mode works only after re inserting the USB pen drive.

Answer (score 0):

Right, the behavior makes perfect sense. You only disabled access *after* the drive was inserted.

Presumably, the system caches that registry value (like it does with most of the registry values) and only reads it when a new device is inserted. Since you have already inserted the device *before* changing the value, the system never has cause to read the new value and prevent you from accessing the drive.

This setting is not really intended to be used the way you're trying to use it. Most people disable access to USB devices on a system one time and then leave it that way. They don't use it to lock themselves out of a device that's currently attached—you can just unplug it.